# Downloading a file in Python 2.x vs 3.x

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm working on a script that checks multiple domain names if they are registered or not. It loops through a list of the domains read from a file, and the registration check is done using enom's API. My problem is the code accessing the API in Python 2:

```
import urllib2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
...
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = ET.fromstring(response.read())
...
return content.find("RRPCode").text
```

generates the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' in nearly 30% of the checks. While the Python 3 code:

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
...
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
content = ET.fromstring(response.read())
...
return content.find("RRPCode").text
```

works fine. I should also mention that the number of errors returned are random and not related to specific domain names.

What could be the cause of these errors?

I am by the way using Python 2.7.3 and Python 3.2.3 on a VPS running Ubuntu 12.04 server.

Thanks.

Comment: Usually `find()` can't find element if those element has another namespace. Look at your xml document: maybe it has namespaces?

Comment: I think the problem is in the way the urllib2 works and not the XML result because if I use this tool to check 1 to say 5 domains it works perfectly. While if I check 10 or more I start getting this error. And if I check the same 10 domains again, I get the error in different ones than the previous check.